# Forcing a program to run a procedure when returning back to a screen

Tags: android, view, focus

i have 2 screens. Screen 1 calls screen 2. When the user returns back to screen 1 how can i force it to run a procedure?

Comment: Is each "screen" handled by it's own, separate, Activity?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Activity per screen, you can reimplement the onResume method.

Comment: ^ This works.. though doesn't onResume() get called when the Activity first starts as well? Worth pointing out.

Comment: Yep, it actually does : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: is there anything that i can use so it dosent get run when it first starts?

Comment: You can set a boolean `firstRun` to `true` in the `onStart()`, and check if it's `true` in `onResume()`. If it is, set it to `false`, if not, simply run your procedure.